# Algorithm to assign courses to requirments

Tags: algorithm, typescript

I am trying determine the best algorithm to use to solve a assigning courses to requirements. Requirements have a certain number of credits before they can be considered fulfilled. And courses have a number of credits earned when taken. So the data structure looks something like :

```
export class Course {
  constructor(public id:number,
              public credits:number) {
  }
}


export class Requirement {
  constructor(public id:number,
              public name:string,
              public credits:number,
              public courses:RequirementCourse[] = []) {
  }
}
```

And given the following dataset :

```
let requirments =  [
       new Requirement(1, 'math',    3, [1,2,3,4]),
       new Requirement(2, 'science', 2, [5]),
       new Requirement(3, 'english', 2, [2,7]),
       new Requirement(4, 'history',     2, [2,8])
     ];

let courses =  [
      new Course(1,1),
      new Course(2,0.5),
      new Course(3,1),
      new Course(4,1),
      new Course(5,1),
      new Course(6,1),
      new Course(7,1),
      new Course(8,1),
      new Course(9,1)
    ]
```

What is the most efficient algorithm to determine how to allocate courses to requirements.

**Note**: the dataset is simplified from the real world use case I have. In particular, courses in the Requirement courses array will have an associated priority. Also, the user will have the ability to manually allocate a course that will need to be assigned to the specified requirement.

**EDIT :** Based on the comments below, the algorithm must conform to the following rules

- A course's credit can not fulfill more than one credit
- If a course has multiple credit's, they can be split among multiple requirements
- if there is not enough credits to fulfill all requirements, the algorithm needs to allocate credits to fill as many requirements as possible
- if two courses can be allocated to the same requirement, and the requirement can not otherwise be fulfilled (i.e. it needs the credit of the conflicting course), the course must be marked as a conflict

Comment: Can courses double count? I.e. if I take course 2, does it count for both math and english? Or can it count for either but not both?

Comment: Good question - A course may only fulfil on requirement

Comment: Is there any metric that determines an "optimal" course allocation? Or just the fastest way to find any satisfactory courseload (or determine that there is no such courseload)? From the first note I presume any valid courseload is acceptable?

Comment: As of right now no, but i could see it happening in the future where courses with higher grades should be preferred. Also, incomplete course loads are acceptable, and unresolvable conflicts can be marked as such, I am going to add a fiddle i have going of a rough draft, which i think could be done better with a defined algorithm

Comment: OK cool. Final question I think - cam a course count partially towards multiple requirements? I.e. if I take a 2 credit course that counts towards two requirements, can I count one credit towards each? The problem is pretty easy if so

Comment: I see a max-flow formulation in the multiple assignment scenario. If it is just all or nothing, the best I see right now is a 0-1 ILP (which would be np-hard).

Comment: My thoughts exactly

Comment: @Mshnik yes, a multiple credit course can fulfil more than one requirement

Comment: @uberwatch what do you mean by all or nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the comments, this is absolutely max flow. Given your inputs, construct the following graph:

- A super source **SOURCE**
- A super sink **SINK**
- for each course:

  - A node **c** representing that course
  - An edge from **SOURCE** to **c** with capacity equal to **c**'s credit count
- for each requirement:

  - A node **r** representing that requirement
  - An edge from **r** to **SINK** with capacity equal to the credit requirement of **r**
- for each course **c** /requirement **r** pair:

  - If the given course satisfies the given requirement, an edge from **c** to **r** with capacity equal to **c**'s credit count

Then just run max flow from **SOURCE** to **SINK**. If the max flow is equal to the total credit requirements of all the requirements, you've found a valid flow. Simply read off the flows on the edges added in the last step to figure out which courses were used for which requirements. If the max flow is some lower number, it is not possible to fill every requirement with the given courses.

Total run time:

- Graph construction (where `C` is number of courses and `R` is number of requirements):

  - Adding nodes: `1 + 1 + C + R = O(C+R)`
  - Adding edges: `C + C*R + R = O(C*R)`
- Running Max Flow

  - Assuming preflow push is algorithm of choice: `O(V^3) = O((C+R)^3)`
- Transforming to problem solution:

  - Checking for max flow validity: `R = O(R)`
  - Reading back into courses: `C*R = O(C*R)`

Therefore I argue the algorithm is bound by `O((C+R)^3)`, the max flow section

Comment: Great answer, i took some time to implement this and so far it is working great. Thanks!